# Moving to first letter in a line

Tags: key-bindings

I've got a line like this:

```
* [ ] Find a way to efficiently move a task from one area to another   #8ab879
```

I want to create a map that selects just "Find a way to efficiently move a task from one area to another" in a visual block. The brackets may or may not be there. The `#8ab879` may or may not be there.

Here's what I got:

`nnoremap \bw ma^/[A-z]<cr>n:set nohls<cr>v$F#be`

Which doesn't quite work (the last bracket is selected) and my method seems awfully convoluted.

Comment: Just open up a ASCII table and check all characters between `A` and `z` or if you are on Linux execute the shell command `echo {A..z}`. This range also contains `[`  `]` `^` `_` and the backtick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `^` followed by `search()`

```
nnoremap <leader>^ ^:call search('\w', '', line('.'))<cr>
```

Note: this uses `\w` which is `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. You may want to make it just `[A-Za-z]` for your use case.

For more help see:

```
:h ^
:h search()
:h line()
```